# How to associate a comment with a parent comment in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have built an application with comments that are commented on a parent comment. I have the following comment model. How can I associate the comment with a parent comment ?

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(max_length=255, default = uuid.uuid4)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    commentinguser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a recursive `ForeignKey` (a foreign key to the same model) by passing "self"

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```